# Using Zend Mail with SMTP Authentication gives an error

Tags: zend-framework, email, zend-mail

I'm trying to create a form that sends an email using SMTP authentication, but I keep receiving an error. I've read a bunch of posts online and this is the code I've come up with so far. Does anyone see anything wrong with the code below? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Bob

```
$configSMTP = array(  
    'port' => 587,  
    'auth' => 'login',  
    'username' => '***',  
    'password' => '***'  
);

$transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('mail.server.com', $configSMTP);  
$mail = new Zend_Mail();

$mail->setReplyTo($config['replyto']);  
$mail->setBodyText($message);  
$mail->setFrom($params[$config['emailID']], $params[$config['nameID']]);  
$mail->addTo($config['sendto']);  
$mail->setSubject($config['subject']);

try {  
    $mail->send($transport);  
} catch(Exception $ex) {  
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('There was an error submitting your  request.');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Mandril's SMTP uses TLS.

http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21738477-What-SMTP-ports-can-I-use-

Enable it in your config array.

```
$configSMTP = array(
    'ssl' => 'tls',  
    'port' => 587,  
    'auth' => 'login',  
    'username' => '***',  
    'password' => '***'  
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Would direct you maybe to section on [resource plugins](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.mail) form Zend Mail.  Give a better list of the options and shows how to assign them through your app.ini file.

That said, assuming your arguments are valid that looks fine.

What exception are you catching?  You must be getting an error message.  Can you telnet from this machine to your mail server?  Want to eliminate network/auth issues.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without knowing what exception you're getting.

There might be several reasons, can you connect to the SMTP-server.. Is the port 587 really open? Do you have a firewall, and if so, might it be blocking the connection to that port? Are you really sure those credentials are valid? Have you tried manually connecting to the SMTP-server?

If not, see how you can do it with Telnet: [How to test an SMTP server using Telnet](http://www.anta.net/misc/telnet-troubleshooting/smtp.shtml)

You could also try using a transactional email service. That way you wouldn't need to manage an SMTP-server or even think about deliverability, etc. You would just outsource it to someone else.

There are various providers, some of them are:

- [AlphaMail](http://comfirm.se/alpha-mail/)
- Mandrill
- PostageApp

If you're using AlphaMail, you could just use the AlphaMail PHP-client and send your emails like the example below:

```
include_once("comfirm.alphamail.client/emailservice.class.php");

$email_service = AlphaMailEmailService::create()
    ->setServiceUrl("http://api.amail.io/v1")
    ->setApiToken("YOUR-ACCOUNT-API-TOKEN-HERE");

$person = new stdClass();
$person->userId = "1234";
$person->firstName = "John";
$person->lastName = "Doe";
$person->dateOfBirth = 1975;

$response = $email_service->queue(EmailMessagePayload::create()
    ->setProjectId(12345) // You AlphaMail project (determines template, options, etc)
    ->setSender(new EmailContact("Sender Company Name", "from@example.com"))
    ->setReceiver(new EmailContact("Joe Doe", "to@example.org"))
    ->setBodyObject($person) // Any serializable object
);
```

The templates are constructed in the AlphaMail Dashboard using the [Comlang](http://docs.amail.io/?section=comlang&client_env=comlang) templating language. This means that you can easily edit your emails at any time, without having to dig through code. Templates in Comlang look something like:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <b>Name:</b> <# payload.firstName " " payload.lastName #><br>
        <b>Date of Birth:</b> <# payload.dateOfBirth #><br>

        <# if (payload.userId != null) { #>
            <a href="/sign-up">Sign Up Free!</a>
        <# } else { #>
            <a href="/login?id=<# payload.userId #>">Sign In</a>
        <# } #>
    </body>
</html>
```